# `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter()` converts some parameter names to `TRUE`

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

Consider a Quarto document with the following YAML header:

```
---
params:
  x: NA
  y: NA
  f: NA
---
```

This header passes validation at https://www.yamllint.com/.

I can read the header with `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter()`:

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(ymlthis)

draw_yml_tree(yaml_front_matter("path/to/myFile.qmd"))
└── params:
    ├── x: NA
    ├── 'TRUE': NA
    └── f: NA
```

but the parameter names are now `x`, `TRUE` and `f`, not `x`, `y` and `f`.  The conversion from `y` to `TRUE` occurs in `yaml_front_matter()`.  I have used `draw_yml_tree()` purely for cosmetic purposes.

I get the same result for parameter names `Y`, `yes` and `Yes`, but `T` and `t` (and `f` as shown above) behave as expected.

I get the same result using `rmarkdown` v2.17 and v2.20.1 (the latest development version on github).

There seems to be no option to modify the behaviour of `yaml_front_matter` by varying parameter values:

```
yaml_front_matter
function (input, encoding = "UTF-8") 
{
    parse_yaml_front_matter(read_utf8(input))
}
```

Have I missed something, or is this a bug?

Comment: Funny. This should likely be a bug-report to `rmarkdown`, that seems rather egregious.

Comment: For context, the issue traces back to `yaml::yaml.load`, not within the `rmarkdown` package itself.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml/issues/122. Also triggered with `n:`.

Comment: fyi, quoting the `y` fixes it, as demonstrated with `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(textConnection("---\nparams:\n  x: NA\n  y: NA\n  f: NA\n---"))` versus `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(textConnection("---\nparams:\n  x: NA\n  'y': NA\n  f: NA\n---"))`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the further research and suggestions.  Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: quote suspect arguments on the lhs of the colons:

```r
rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(textConnection("---\nparams:\n  x: NA\n  y: NA\n  f: NA\n---"))
# $params
# $params$x
# [1] "NA"
# $params$`TRUE`
# [1] "NA"
# $params$f
# [1] "NA"
rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(textConnection("---\nparams:\n  x: NA\n  'y': NA\n  f: NA\n---"))
# $params
# $params$x
# [1] "NA"
# $params$y
# [1] "NA"
# $params$f
# [1] "NA"
```

**Background:** this bug traces back to [yaml#122](https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml/issues/122). There's a *suggestion* that this may be resolved in the YAML 1.2 spec, though apparently the `yaml` author believes progress on that to be stagnated. I've not verified the spec-claim; after diving into the C-code in https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml (R's `yaml` package source), it's not clear if the default method of parsing yaml "events" enabled discrimination between *key token* and *value token* (though the `*token` struct may include it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the c yaml library used for the package is still officially only yaml 1.1. It's been inching towards full yaml 1.2 support, but it's not there yet. This behavior is a consequence of expecting yaml 1.2 behavior when it's 1.1.